# Apache .htaccess rewrite rule with 2 GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I am working on a CMS that requires an `id` and a `title` to be sent to the page `content.php` so that the data can be fetched from the database. I have tried to use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*) content.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

But when I navigate to /id, it doesn't work, nor does it work if i do `/id/title`. What have I messed up here? Anything to remember for future use in `.htaccess`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post an example of the incoming URL with the `id` and `title` parameters in it. Because they have to be in that URL to be able to pass them as key-value pairs to the script `content.php`. They can't be guessed.

Comment: @felipealamedaa what do you mean... I mean didn't I already to post it  in my question? Thanks!

Comment: Not really. It is not clear how to get those values. For example: The URL `http://examplec.com/id/title/` holds those values and can be passed to `content.php` as a query. Otherwise, ¿where are those values or parameters?

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA so is that clearer, if this helps, the urls on stackoverflow are what I am modelling this on.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ content.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ content.php?id=$1&title=$2
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ content.php?q=$2&cat=$1&p=1` works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)/([^/]+)
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/content.php?key1=%1&key2=%2  [L]
```

It will map silently this:

`http://example.com/id/title`

To this:

`http://example.com/content.php?key1=id&key2=title`

Where `/id` in the incoming URL is the value of `id` key and the same for `/title`

Comment: thanks a lot! but just out of interest, what was wrong with my original rule?

Comment: The first back reference is limited to digits and the second one to everything including slashes so I think that might be, although I never tested.